# Table formatting alignment in Jira

Tags: formatting, jira

I have the following table format in Jira:

```
||A            ||  B  ||   C    ||
||             || 0059||Warranty||
||OFFER DISPLAY||OFFER DISPLAY NAME   |Lite|
||             ||OFFER DETAILS DISPLAY|  Reconditioned Genie Lite |
||             ||AA |$0|
||             ||BB |N/A|
||             ||CC |N/A|
```

I need the row headers "AA", "BB" and "CC" to be aligned to the left. I have checked [Text Formatting Notation Help](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all)
but I haven't seen a way to align table headers.

Does anybody know how to align headers (in this case, row headers) to either right or left?

Comment: Looks like JIRA table header always align to center and table content always align to left. there is no way to adjust it. It is OK to let header to center, but sometimes we need some of the column content to be center, like to display the marker, unfortunately it can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this format '||' for table headers and '|' for the table rows

```
||heading 1||heading 2||heading 3||
|col A1|col A2|col A3|
|col B1|col B2|col B3|
```

Answer (score 6):

To do left aligned, don't do the table headers, instead make them Strong:

```
|*A*            |  *B*  |   *C*    |
|               |0059|Warranty|
|*OFFER DISPLAY*|OFFER DISPLAY NAME   |Lite|
|               |OFFER DETAILS DISPLAY|  Reconditioned Genie Lite |
|               |AA |$0|
|               |BB |N/A|
|               |CC |N/A|
```

If you want right aligned, doesn't look like there's a clean way to do it without doing some sort of `{noformat}` tag type header.

Comment: problem is that it won't have the gray background

Comment: Your option for changing backgrounds is to use Panels but it won't look very nice at all otherwise there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a transparent image with a size of 1px by 1px and inserted it in the column headers with the minimum size I wanted the columns to be. To make the header text vertically centered, I needed to insert this before and after the text. See the following example:

```
|| !for_formatting_only.png|width=50px, height=1px! Col1 !for_formatting_only.png|width=50px, height=1px! || Col2 || Col3 ||
|| Row header | Content of column 1 | Content of column 2 |
```